# I developed a website. I want to know where to give the start up page URL

Tags: asp.net

I have one doubt. I developed a website using entity framework.

I want to know where to give the `URL` for `login page`??
My start up page is my **login page**

I want to know how to give the default page URL.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Are you asking an advice which page should be default (some home page or login page) or just asking how to make login page to be default?

Comment: entity framework has nothing to do with the authentication

Comment: if you have hosted website on IIS you can set default page there using settings provided by IIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using the Authentication then using the WebConfig you can define the defaultUrl
ex.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="member_login.aspx"
    defaultUrl="index.aspx" />
</authentication>
```